# Variance- covariance matrix in multivariate regression.

Tags: regression

I have a multivariate model with 3 responses and 6 input variables. Three responses models are fitted with different model parameters. In such case how to find variance covariance matrix for output responses

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~jennings/stat514/stat512notes/topic3.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiN5_-U5J_UAhUIr48KHZR5D1IQFggoMAE&usg=AFQjCNFgytU1Sg7nUwtFKycpa7rAOXYYYQ

Comment: Here the models are fitted with the same explanatory variable. The model which I have has different explanatory variables in each response function. Let us say I have 6 input variables and only 4 of them appear in 1st response function and only 5 of them appear in 2nd response function.